# How to get the response of bounced mail when working with google mail smtp (smtp.googlemail.com)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am working on making newsletters. I have bulk of *1200 emails* but it's not verified. I am using google mail smtp for verification in **codeigniter** framework. Mail is properly sending but when I tested it for wrong email then also it shows send mail status. I want to ask that how to get the response of bounced mail when working with google mail smtp.

`$check` is containing array of emails :

```
 $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
            'send_multipart' => FALSE
        );
        $this->email->initialize($config);  
        $this->load->library('email', $config);

        foreach($_POST['chk'] as $check) 
        {
                    $this->email->clear();
                    $data = array(
                     'userName'=> 'Myname'
                         );
                   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");   
                   $this->load->library('email',$config);




                   $this->email->from("mymail@gmail.com","Myname");

                    //echo $row->email;
                    $this->email->to($check);
                    $this->email->subject("THIS IS AN EMAIL TEST");
                    $gett = $this->load->view('home_test.php',$data,TRUE);
                    $this->email->message($gett);  
                    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                    if($this->email->send())
                    {
                        echo "Your Mail send";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                        exit();
                    }
        }
```

Its always showing Your Mail send although if I provide fake email id. How to track this bounced mail in **PHP**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get status of the bounced emails immediately after sent. What you can do is, specify return path email as third parameter of `$this->email->from("mymail@gmail.com","Myname");`.

Change this line

`$this->email->from("mymail@gmail.com","Myname");`

to

`$this->email->from("mymail@gmail.com","Myname", 'yourreturnemail@gmail.com');`

For more details see codigniter's email documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#class-reference)

This way all bounced emails will come to the return path email address. Then you can create a cron or something to read and parse this emails.  php's `imap` [extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) can be installed and use for read email bounced status.